# RestKit+CoreData+MagicalRecord: how not to persist managed objects

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, magicalrecord

I have a webservice which returns a list of objects (hundreds of products) which don't need to be persisted but just temporary displayed.

The user can select any of them and such items must be saved into the database.

Is it possible to manage this scenario with just one NSManagedObject entity?

Using this respose descriptor:

```
- (id)productsResultResponseDescriptor {

    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Product class]];
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"products" toKeyPath:@"products" withMapping:[Product mapping]]];  
    ...
    return productsResultResponseDescriptor;
}

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                   @"name":@"name",
                                   @"category":@"category"
                                }];
    return mapping;
}
```

With this configuration I get a bad access exception in the validateValue method of RKMappingOperation.

Could it work or am I supposed to have two different objects

```
Product : NSObject
ManagedProduct : NSManagedObject
```

and use the former for data retrieve with RestKit and the latter for saving the chosen products with MagicalRecord?

Many thanks,
DAN

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to solve this issue? Could you provide some code if you did? Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save them all. Core data will make it much easier for you to load only the required data for display when you have significantly more data than can fit on one screen. Then, just add a flag to your entity which is set (and saved) when the user selects or deselects a product.

Note that you could do it using a plain and a managed object but it's more code and complexity for you and it's less efficient both in terms of memory and processor usage.

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks for your reply. Every time the user performs a new search hundreds of products would be saved and then removed at the next one. This is why I'm not sure about saving them with Core data.
Taking into account this scenario I would go with the solution of using a plain and a managed object, saving only the selected items (a kind of wish list) with the managed one, do you agree?

Comment: Personally I would still save them all. Updates and deletion can both be done in the background if need be. I'd only not use Core Data if the search results were smaller (like 10 or 20) and I had no requirement for scrolling through them / pagination. I don't want hundreds of results in memory at the same time when the user can only see a handful...

Comment: Saving them all how would you handle the chosen items keeping them ordered? I need to show the selected ones in an ordered list.

Comment: Selection order? What about deselection? It depends on the requirements. Add an attribute with the 'selection count'.

Comment: There's no deselection, the list can only be emptied. The last selected item must be the first of the list.

Comment: Perfect. So you can add the count of selected items to the newly selected item and then sort in descending order.